# LINQ: How to introduce where in Include?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query that I am using to get students, I also want to include the current course in which student is studying. How to change this query to make it work?

```
var students = Context.Students
                      .Where(x=>x.Race == "SomeRace")
                      .Include(x=> x.StudentCourse.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Status == CourseStatus.Current))
```

This query will through an error, since EF does not allow to put where condition in the Include. Any turn around? Any other way to write this query?

**Update**:
If I use the solution proposed by @CoryNelson which is something like this:

```
studentResult = Context.Students
.Where(x=>x.Race == "SomeRace")
.Select(x=>new
{
    Student = x,
    CurrentCourse = x.StudentCourse
        .FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Status == CourseStatus.Current)
};
```

The studentResult I get is not a list, like if I try to do

```
foreach( student in studentResult) 
{ 
   finalResult.Add( 
   new StudentDto
  { 
      FirstName = student.Firstname // I do not get student first name, intellisense is not letting me select FirstName, which means studentResult is not a collection? 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Filtered `Include` is a recurring issue. It's just not possible. As for your last effort, try `student.Student.Firstname`. You're looping through anonymous types from the previous statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Include` wrong. `Include` is used to force eager loading on a entity that is connected to the entities you are bringing back. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on `Include`.

What you are trying to do should be in the where statement along with the other selector criteria.

**Updated**

Then you do want to use Cory Nelson's LINQ query.

```
var students = Context.Students
                      .Where(x => x.Race == "SomeRace")
                      .Select(x => new
                      {
                          Student = x,
                          CurrentCouse = x.StudentCourse.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Status == CourseStatus.Current)
                      });
```

Then in order to access them you do something like:

```
foreach(var s in students)
{
    finalResult.Add(new StudentDto { FirstName = s.Student.Firstname } );
}
```

The use of `new` in the `Select` creates an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). By saying `Student = x` you are saying the anonymous type has a field called Student which will have the fields of the orginal variable `x` which was of the `Student` class. The article provided has more details on anonymous types but that is all you should need to access the fields.

Comment: I can not use this,  I want all paitents with some race and the current course. It might filter the results and not return students if the student does not has any current course.

Comment: @Obviously Just to clarify before I update anything, you want all students with "SomeRace" and any course that is current? Not a specific current course but any current course?

Comment: Ideally there will be just one student course that is current, so i can select FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Yes that was the issue, now its working

Answer (score 1):

`Include` brings in all or none of a navigation property. You might want to use a projection instead:

```
Context.Students
    .Where(x=>x.Race == "SomeRace")
    .Select(x=>new
    {
        Student = x,
        CurrentCourse = x.StudentCourse
            .FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Status == CourseStatus.Current)
    };
```

Comment: This should work, but when I do this and try to populate the result(which should be collection)  I do not get intellesense. Why is that?

Comment: foreach( student in result)
{
new StudentDto{
FirstName = student.Firstname // I do not get student, intellisense is not letting me select FirstName




}

}